# Annoying grey flicker during updates in ttk GUI

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.4, ttk

I am trying to populate my screen with some data that refreshes every given time interval. I am using Python3, themed tkinter. Every time my screen updates I see grey flickerings on screen for every label. Is there a way to avoid this?
P.S : I am calling the 'after' method to refresh data.

UPDATE: Here is some example code:

```
def button1Click(self):
    self.top = Toplevel(width=600,height=400)
    self.top.title("XYZ ORGANIZATION")
    self.frame1 = Frame(self.top,bg='#009999')
    self.frame1.pack()
    self.noOfEmp = Label(self.frame1,text = "Number_Of_Employees : ", font =('Verdana',9, 'bold'),bg='#009999',fg = '#000000')
    self.noOfEmp.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=W,padx=0,pady=5)
    self.TeamLabel = Label(self.frame1,text = "Team Name : ", font =('Verdana',9, 'bold'),bg='#009999',fg = '#000000')
    self.TeamLabel.grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=W,padx=0,pady=5)      

    self.text = Text(self.frame1, bg='#009999')
    self.text.grid(row=8,columnspan=17)
    self.old_emp = 0
    self.EFile = open('/abc','r').readlines()
    for line in self.EFile:
        if line.startswith('EmpTotal:'):
            self.Tot_Emp = int(line.split()[1])
            break
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=self.__make_layout, args = ())
    t1.daemon = True
    t1.start()
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=self.ProcEmp,args = ())
    t2.daemon = True
    t2.start()

def self.__make_layout:
    self.CLabelVal = Label(self.frame1,text = CSpace, font=('Verdana',9),bg='#009999',fg = '#000000')
    self.MLabelVal = Label(self.frame1,text = MSpace  , font =('Verdana',9),bg='#009999',fg = '#000000')
    self.Label1Val.grid(row=4,column=1,sticky=W+E+N+S,padx=5,pady=5)                              
    self.Label2Val.grid(row=5,column=1,sticky=W+E+N+S,padx=5,pady=5)
    self.frame1.after(5000,self.__make_layout)
```

Comment: There probably is a way. Without seeing code that duplicates the problem, I doubt there's any way we can give you a useful answer. See http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Add to your question the *simplest* code you can get that displays the problem for you.  Ditto to the rest of Bryan's answer.

Comment: I am using 'after' to populate and refresh data at every 2 sec Interval. So every time the data is updated on my GUI, I can see some grey background block for my output data. Since it displays different numbers every 2 seconds, the grey flicker appears constantly.

Comment: Do you create new widgets every 2 (5?) seconds? If so, do you delete the old ones first, and is there a reason you create new widgets rather than updating the existing widgets?

Comment: Are you saying the "flickering" isn't actually a flicker, but that the length of the strings changes, and the amount of space they take up is different?

Comment: I am trying to populate some fields with new data every 2 seconds. I do not intend on creating new labels with every interval, just the data(value) for each field should be updated/refreshed with new data(after some simple arithmetic operations). By Flicker i mean every 2 secs, when new data is written on screen it flashes a grey box in the background of the new data.. I am unable to capture the same in a picture. All I can think of now is, the flicker is similar to the ones that you get to see on TV immediately after you power off and it shuts down.. Sorry for such a bad explanation! –

Comment: @Dee: you need to show us the _smallest_ amount of code to duplicate the problem. The only code you showed us is where you create the labels, you haven't shown us code where you update it, and you haven't shown us what the GUI looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of the problem is that you keep stacking more and more widgets on top of each other. You should create the labels exactly once, and then change what they display every five seconds, instead of creating new widgets every five seconds.

There's also the problem that you're creating the labels in a thread. Tkinter isn't thread safe. Any code that creates or modifies a widget needs to be in the main thread. To update the labels you don't need threads, though you can use a thread to change what actually gets displayed.

```
def __make_layout(self):
    self.CLabelVal = Label(...,text = CSpace, ...)
    self.MLabelVal = Label(...,text = MSpace, ...)
    self.Label1Val.grid(...)                              
    self.Label2Val.grid(...)

def __update_layout(self):
    self.CLabelVal.configure(text=CSpace)
    self.MLabelVal.configure(text=MSpace)
    self.after(5000, self.__update_layout)
```

Comment: Totally Worked! Thank you so much for all the help!!

Answer (score 0):

I made a small program based on what you provided.

This is what i got. I chose 500ms instead because i did not want to wait that long. I ran two internet videos at the same time and had no issues.
So my best guess you have a slow video card or over loaded computer.

```
from tkinter import *

class MyClass:

    frame1 = Tk()
    poll = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.frame1.after(500, self.__make_layout)

    def __make_layout(self):
        self.poll += 1
        CSpace = "Poll count = "*20
        MSpace = str(self.poll)

        self.CLabelVal = Label(self.frame1, text=CSpace, font=('Verdana', 9), bg='#009999', fg='#000000')
        self.MLabelVal = Label(self.frame1, text=MSpace, font=('Verdana', 9), bg='#009999', fg='#000000')
        self.CLabelVal.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=W+E+N+S, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.MLabelVal.grid(row=5, column=1, sticky=W+E+N+S, padx=5, pady=5)
        print(CSpace, MSpace)
        return self.frame1.after(500, self.__make_layout)


MyClass()
mainloop()
```

Comment: This isn't a very good example. It will create thousands of label widgets in a matter of minutes. You don't need to continually make new widgets, you only need to modify the text of the existing widges.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing but got lazy. There wasn't much to go with. I was thinking about using textvariable. Im new to Tk.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't create more labels and uses the "textvariable" update feature.

```
from tkinter import *


class MyClass:
    frame1 = Tk()
    poll = 0
    textstg = StringVar()
    CSpace = "Poll count"

    def __init__(self):
        self.frame1.after(500, self.__make_layout)
        self.CLabelVal = Label(self.frame1, text=self.CSpace, font=('Verdana', 9), bg='#009999', fg='#000000')
        self.MLabelVal = Label(self.frame1, textvariable=self.textstg, font=('Verdana', 9), bg='#009999', fg='#000000')
        self.CLabelVal.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=W+E+N+S, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.MLabelVal.grid(row=5, column=1, sticky=W+E+N+S, padx=5, pady=5)

    def __make_layout(self):
        self.poll += 1
        self.textstg.set(str(self.poll))
        return self.frame1.after(50, self.__make_layout)

MyClass()
mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks @James, I will try to use poll.